# Excel Match Multiple Criteria with OR

Tags: excel, match

I have below code currently to match two criteria:

```
=INDEX(Dict!$A$2:$AK$500, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($K$1, Dict!$F$2:$F$500)*(COUNTIF($J$1, Dict!$G$2:$G$500)), ROW(Dict!$A$2:$AK$500)-MIN(ROW(Dict!$A$2:$AK$500))+1), ROW(F1)), COLUMN(F1))
```

Criteria are J1 and K1. For J1, I need to use 2 values instead, achieveing K1 AND (J1 OR I1).  Thanks for helping

Comment: `AND` translates to multiplication and `OR` is addition. So try to structure your calculations like: `K*J + K*I`

Comment: please post your excel sheet here